# Was the Mana-Bomb seen at Firewing Point the same type used on Theramore?

Tags: warcraft

In "Burning Crusade", the first expansion for World of WarCraft, a questline in Terokkar Forest took players to Firewing Point. The point of the quests were to investigate, and later destroy, a weapon the Blood Elves there were experimenting with - a bomb of pure energy that could destroy an entire town. Although not officially named at that time, one character DID refer to it as "a mana bomb".

Cut to "Mists of Pandaria", the fourth expansion, and we see the Alliance town of Theramore attacked by the Horde, ultimately being

> destroyed by a mana bomb, albeit a much more powerful one that left a crater where the town once stood. This event kicked off a period of increased tensions between the Horde and Alliance factions, ultimately driving Jaina Proudmoore a little insane as well.

The latter device seems to have been built by goblins, with players following it from Orgrimmar down through the Barrens (either to escort it as Horde or stop it as Alliance).

**Are these two devices the same technology and/or design, and were the Blood Elves directly involved with the building of the second one?**

Comment: I vaguely recall there was a Blue Dragon artifact of some kind at the center of the Theramore bomb.  I don't recall details however.